# How should I generate the time windows data for solving VRPTW problem with or-tools?

Tags: python, or-tools, vehicle-routing

I am pretty new in or-tools and I've been trying to implement the vrptw algorithm to a microservice that calculates the possible routes; furthermore, the service has been provided with the duration matrix, vehicles and routes but not the time windows matrix. How should I generate the time matrix to follow or-tools's solution or how should I approach it? I have seen or-tools's vrptw example but I couldn't figure out how can I build this matrix so your help is crucially precious.
Thank you very much.

Comment: The time windows should be given. For example Delivery A can only be done between 1300H and 1600H. You can't get this information anywhere aside from withing your business.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Actually, I have jobs dict, and inside of it, I have service field which represents the remaining delivery time as in seconds format.  I'd be really appreciated if you could explain that how should I get service(remaining delivery seconds) data into a range like in or-tools example (0, 5), (7-12) and etc. jobs dict =>  "jobs": [
 ...
    {
      "id": 2,
      "location_index": 5,
      "service": 327 # remaining delivery seconds
    }...]

Comment: I don't get it. How do you get the remaining delivery time?

Comment: I have a http microservice that gets vehicles, jobs and duration matrix but not time windows.  Here an example of matrix data: "matrix":[[0,516,226,853,1008,1729,346,1353,1554,827],[548,0,474,1292,1442,2170,373,1801,1989,1068],[428,466,0,1103,1175,1998,226,1561,1715,947],[663,1119,753,0,350,1063,901,681,814,1111],[906,1395,1003,292,0,822,1058,479,600,1518],[1488,1994,1591,905,776,0,1746,603,405,1676],[521,357,226,1095,1167,1987,0,1552,1705,1051],[1092,1590,1191,609,485,627,1353,0,422,1583],[1334,1843,1436,734,609,396,1562,421,0,1745],[858,1186,864,1042,1229,1879,984,1525,1759,0]]

Comment: Like I said. It is up to you how to build this. No one on SO would know this, but you and your team. Maybe you want to have another microservice that gets the time windows for each delivery - or maybe talk to the rest of your team on where to get the data you need.

Comment: I do get your point well but what I mean is I have also remaining delivery times under the jobs key   "jobs": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "location_index": 3,
      "delivery": [
        2
      ],
      "service": 327
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "location_index": 4,
      "delivery": [
        1
      ],
      "service": 391
    }, ...] Here service field stands for the service duration in terms of seconds. I've been trying to understand still can't I have time_windows (by generating) data from those,can I ?

Comment: If the remaining delivery time defines the end of the time window then you can just set the time window as per the documentation with start the start moment of your problem and end the remaining service time.